# htaccess + htpasswd: how to prevent executing php scripts without specifying a password

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, .htaccess, http-basic-authentication, .htpasswd

My site is managed by Apache on Linux. In the base directory, there is the sub folder fill. In this subfolder, there is a php script: do.php

Here is my .htaccess:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName 'Welcome back'
AuthUserFile /home/provider/mysite/fill/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

Here is my .htpasswd:

```
ab12:2yd32253zi7Nz2
```

When I go to http://mysite/fill, I am asked a username and a password. When I specify them (ab12 with the password), I login successfully and see the content of index.html located in this fill folder (i.e. http://mysite/fill/index.html). Then, I clear browsing history and all the passwords saved earlier. After that, when I run the script http://mysite/fill/do.php, I am NOT asked for any authentication.

**The question**: is it possible to ask for credentials when running http://mysite/fill/do.php? Any changes in htaccess?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you clear your cookies at the same time as clearing other data?

Comment: Yes, I tried to clean everything including cookies. Actually, not sure the reason for this behavior is that I didn't logout properly. I tried it with a clean browser where I have never got to mysite. The problem is that I am not asked a password even when I go to mysite/fill/do.php on the clean browser...

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/auth.html) on *Authentication, Authorization, and Access Control*, unfortunately it seems that **it is not possible to logout.**

So the problem is not that http://mysite/fill/do.php is not asking for credentials. The actual problem here is that you are not able to reset the authentication.

> **How do I log out?**
>
> Since browsers first started implementing basic authentication,
>   website administrators have wanted to know how to let the user log
>   out. Since the browser caches the username and password with the
>   authentication realm, as described earlier in this tutorial, this is
>   not a function of the server configuration, but is a question of
>   getting the browser to forget the credential information, so that the
>   next time the resource is requested, the username and password must be
>   supplied again. There are numerous situations in which this is
>   desirable, such as when using a browser in a public location, and not
>   wishing to leave the browser logged in, so that the next person can
>   get into your bank account.
>
> However, although this is perhaps the most frequently asked question
>   about basic authentication, thus far none of the major browser
>   manufacturers have seen this as being a desirable feature to put into
>   their products.
>
> Consequently, the answer to this question is, you can't. Sorry.

Looking at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7682063/how-to-logout-of-an-http-authentication-htaccess-that-works-in-google-chrome), you might be able to reserach other ways to logout.

Comment: Hi Victor, actually, not sure the reason for this behavior is that I didn't logout properly. I tried it with a clean browser where I have never got to http://mysite. The problem is that I am not asked a password even when I go to http://mysite/fill/do.php on the clean browser...

Comment: Can you show your full configuration? I suspect that your directory block may not be properly configured.

Comment: it is exactly full configuration. There is nothing else in .htaccess and .htpassword than described above.

Comment: Actually [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22271768/7323888) might solve your issues, let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you Victor. As far as I can see this solution is for quite another problem. Also, the solution includes not only a RewriteRule string in .htaccess but also some playing with basic auth in the php script itself. That's a bit strange for me. I just thought it is somehow should be implemented with .htaccess and .htpasswd only. But thank you so much for your help and attention.